# convert big endian to little endian of an array which is part of a structure

Tags: c, arrays

I have a structure which has these two elements:

```
_HEADER  tHeader;                   
uint8_t  abData[DATA_SIZE];
```

As you can see it has got a header which is full of `uint` numbers and an array with size `DATA_SIZE`

I want to send this array in some project (not necessary to describe for the problem) and have a problem. The destination expects little endian of the abData[DATA_SIZE] but it is bigendian.. the header doesnt matter- it's correct.

I'm really new in C so I dont know how to convert :/ googling is even more confusing so maybe you can give me a clue how to figure out! Is there a short function I can use to convert this array? The data in the array was copied from a structure including only uints... so maybe I can change the structure before copying or how would you pros handle that?

Comment: The first thing is that abData should be in fact an array of uints if endianess is relevant. The next thing is that you should swap the endianess before sending the data or after receiving the data.

Comment: but isnt it an array of uint? its uint8_t so am i wrong? i cant change the type of the data its "fixed" what would u do before or after? and how would u do? thanks for ur fast answer

Comment: AFAIK, the bits within a byte are always stored in the same order. Machine endianess alters how bytes in multi-byte data elements are stored. So, a little endian 254 would be 0xFE, as would a big-endian one.However, a little-endian 256 would be 0x00, 0x01 while a big-endian one would be 0x01, 0x00. This is the reason I believe for chmikes comment - he's saying the array should be uint16 rather than uint8, since uint16s consume more than 1 byte of storage they can also be affected by changes in endianess. Make it an array of uint16 then pass each byte of the int in the right (expected) order.

Comment: You didn't specify if the values are 16bits or 32bits. The data is probably encoded in network byte order (bigendian) so you need to convert it into host byte order (littleendian). To do this you have to use the ntohs(uint16_t) function or ntohl(uint32_t) function according to the size of the values you want to byte swap.

Comment: @chmike ntoh won't necessarily help. It's the far end which is little-endian, not (necessarily) the host. Anyway, if `abData` is truly `uint8_t`, endianness is irrelevant.

Comment: @kdopen, the question is lacking information. It's not specified if the data to decode is in network byte order or just bigendian. It is also not specified how he concludes the endianess is wrong. There is a missing step in the decoded process. Anyway, the decoder has to swap the bytes in abData. He could do it manually.